# How to exceed .xls excel drop down cell values length using PHPExcel

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, phpexcel

I guys sorry for my English but i need help i am using **PHPExcel** Library for creation of **xls** file in PHP. i am making a drop down in this xls using this code

```
$objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
$objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
$objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
$objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
$objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
$objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
$objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
$objValidation->setFormula1('"Item A,Item B,Item C,Item D,Item E,Item F"');
```

Its working fine but it only allow you to enter **250 characters** only in this `setFormula1` for this drop down cell if i enter more than 250 its not working. How can i enter values more than this **250** limit i have googled it but couldn't find any solution .....

Comment: The limit is 255 characters. You can not exceed this. Its one of the many limitations of PHPExcel (which is why it shouldn't be used!)

Comment: can i use any other library for this purpose..? or any other way to do this

Comment: I have found trying to process Excel with PHP is slow a painful and you are much better off making a service in another programming language and exposing it as an API.

Comment: in excel can we exceed this length manually or its not possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Despite Anthony's comments and criticism of PHPExcel, this is not a PHPExcel limitation, it's an MS Excel limitation, and the way to overcome it is the same as it is in MS Excel itself.

You don't define the list of dropdown options directly in the formula; you define a range of cells containing the options (perhaps in a hidden worksheet), and then set the formula to an actual formula, e.g. `='DropdownSheet'!A1:A100`

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i write this formula because its giving me error..?

Comment: $objValidation->setFormula1("=DropdownSheet!$A:$A");
i am writing like this but its not working..? 
i also wrote like this 
$objValidation->setFormula1("='DropdownSheet'!A1:A9");

its not working can you please tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: Don't try using column ranges like `$A:$A"` but have you set up a worksheet called `DropdownSheet`, with values in cells `A1` to `A9`?

Comment: Take a look at `15datavalidation.php` in the `/Examples` folder that actually uses this approach to a dropdown list for cell `B7`

Comment: Thanks found solution from that this is the way to write
$objValidation->setFormula1('$D$2:$D$6'); // Make sure NOT to put a range of cells or a formula between " and "  !!!

Comment: Yes, my bad.... I'd forgotten that it's always treated as a formula anyway, so you don't prefix with the `=`

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: another thing how can i make this functionality whole column right now its only working for B1 not for B2 etc how can i make this for whole B column

Comment: You need to apply it to each cell individually

Comment: how can i set this individually  it depends on user may be he/she enter 100 or may be 1000 rows... ?

Comment: You need to work out how many rows they've added, and set data validation for each cell in turn: `for($row = 7; $row <= 10; $row++) {
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E'.$row)->getDataValidation(); ..... }`

Comment: Hi @Mark Baker sorry for disturbing you again how can i link dropdown values to ranged name cell like i previously did like this
$objValidation->setFormula1('$D$2:$D$6'); 
now i have named range D2:D6 countries_list
now how can i do link again with countries_list in PHPExcel

Comment: `$objValidation->setFormula1('countries_list');` should work; though I'll run some tests tonight to make sure

Comment: @MarkBaker  can you please let me know how can i use list that has more than 255 chars.
//See this snippet



$list = "Beige, Black, Blue, Bronze, Brown, Burgundy, Charcoal, Copper, Cream, Dark Blue, Dark Grey, Gold, Green, Grey, Light Blue, Light Green, Light Grey, Maroon, Metallic, Multi, Not Specified, Orange, Other, Pink, Purple, Red, Silver, Tan, Unspecified, White,Yellow";

$objValidation->setFormula1('"' . $list . '"');

Comment: @Aasifkhan - Store the values in cells on a worksheet (hidden if you want) and then reference that cell range as your list... this is explained in the [docs](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-data-validation-on-a-cell) and there's also a [fancy example](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/Basic/39_Dropdown.php#L113) of how to dynamically modify this list

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks brother i did it and it works